# Ninject constructor parameter depending on context

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have

```
interface IConfigurationSource
{
      ....
}
```

and

```
class FileConfigurationSource : IConfigurationSource
{
      FileConfigurationSource(string fileName)
      {
           ...
      }
}
```

I have to use `FileConfigurationSource` in two different places with say "Config1.xml" in ClassA and "Config2.xml" in ClassB. How do I used ninject to supply the right parameter based on context or is that violating IoC/DI pattern?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.WhenInjectedInto  can be used to change what is injected in differing targets.  This doesn't violate IoC IMHO because you are making it someone elses responsibility to determine the dependency not the class itself.

Something like

```
 IConfigurationSource source2 = new FileConfigurationSource("Config2.xml");

 kernel.Bind<IConfigurationSource>().ToConstant(source2).WhenInjectedInto<ClassB>();
```

Comment: why bind to constant though? wouldnt binding ToMethod() or binding using To<T>().WithContstructorArgument be better?

Comment: @ArronHS you can do it that way I just find the WithContstructorArgument syntax kind of more difficult to read so I personally avoid it. However if I had a lot of differing permutations I would consider delegating the creation of the object to a factory... and using like you said "ToMethod"

Comment: Note... you should be wary of the way I did it because it implies a singleton... if you really needed a "NEW" object for each you should impliment this the way AaronHS suggested